# SQL Server CASE statement in where clause dependent on column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure with a `select` statement and I am trying to add a `case` statement that if the type is column `[si.TYPE]` is `NEW` then it will filter based on if the `MSRP` is between 2 values and if the column `[si.TYPE]` is `USED` it will filter based on if the `SELLINGPRICE` is between 2 values.

There error is showing on the first `BETWEEN`:

> Incorrect syntax near BETWEEN

Code:

```
SELECT .... 
FROM .... 
WHERE.....

     AND CASE si.[type]
         WHEN 'new' THEN si.[msrp] BETWEEN @priceMin AND @priceMax 
         WHEN 'used' THEN si.[sellingprice] BETWEEN @priceMin AND @priceMax
     END;
```

Will I need to do 2 separate selects and then `UNION` the results to achieve this? It works in MySQL just need to find the solution in SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, you have boolean expressions, and you have non-boolean expressions. The syntax determines which type it is, and boolean expressions cannot be used where non-boolean expressions are expected. MySQL allows them to be mixed more freely. You'll have to rework your syntax; one possible way would be

```
 SELECT .... 
 FROM .... 
 WHERE.....
 AND (si.[type] = 'new' AND si.[msrp] BETWEEN @priceMin and @priceMax
      OR si.[type] = 'used' AND si.[sellingprice] BETWEEN @priceMin and @priceMax)
```